# How to click the nth button position within parent

Tags: javascript, button

I want to click a button based on its nth position within its parent

I have tried includes(), contains(), and filter(). But I either did not do it right or it doesn't work or works only for arrays.

I want to click the 5th button in a grid of buttons of the class "size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button"

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: what kind of grid? you have to show this part of the HTML code, it can be a lot of different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.size-grid-dropdown.size-grid-button')[4].click()
```

Comment: It tells me there is an uncaught type error saying "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:75"

Comment: the exact link I am trying to do it on is https://www.nike.com/launch/t/air-jordan-4-flyknit-hyper-royal/

Comment: It says not to say thanks but I'm saying it anyways, I've been trying to figure that out for like 2 days and you did it in a single line of code, I realize now my lack of knowledge in javascript and I thank you so much.